# Cant create png file to draw Decision Tree with Graphviz (Python)

Tags: python, graphviz, pydot, pydotplus

When running a .py file, while trying to create a PNG file previously created I receive this error

```
pydotplus.graphviz.InvocationException: Program terminated with status: 1. stderr follows: Format: "png" not recognized. Use one of:
```

I don't receive anymore information.
I have already installed pydot, pydotplus, graphviz but the problem keeps happening.

The code that triggers the error is:

```
graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue())  
graph.write_png(filename)
```

By watching the filesystem, I can see that the file is created but has 0Kb and can't be open. So, the write wasn't probably successful.

Any suggestion?

**Edit: Solved.**

Had to reinstall Graphviz, set the Environment variable (manually) in Windows, restart computer and the image was created.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this in your Anaconda prompt  :

```
conda install pydotplus
```

I was facing the same issue and running this command fixed it for me. I was using a pip installation earlier, and that somehow seems to conflict with Jupyter.

Comment: Had to reinstall Graphviz, set the Environment variable (manually) in Windows, restart computer and the image was then created.